# fatal: Not a git repository?

Tags: git, patch, yocto

In order to build and install Yocto for SMA-IMX6, I  created a folder  and then ran `sudo apt-get install git`.

I could not download the source code directly, so I first downloaded the kernel `linux-imx6-imx_3.14.28_1.0.0_ga-bcm`,
then  downloaded  the patch  file `REV-SA01-KERNEL-PATCH-3.14.28-1.0.0`.
After that, I tried to  apply the  patch to the kernel:

```
$ git am ../REV-SA01-KERNEL-PATCH-3.14.28-1.0.0/*.patch
```

But I got this error:

fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

How can I solve  this? Is there any other method to patch?

Comment: Do you want to install yocto (whatever that is) or patch it? Do you want to patch yocto or the kernel? How is git relevant? Please [edit] your question and explain what you are trying to do in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You should look up what [git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) is: it's a version control system. For you, the basic usage is to download a copy of a repository with `git clone …`. This downloads not only a particular version of the source code, but *all* the versions of the source code, including proposed variants and change logs. All this extra information is in a [hidden directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory) called `.git`. You can use `git` commands such as `git checkout`, `git am`, etc. to manipulate the content of the directory and apply patches.

If you've downloaded an archive (e.g. a `.tgz`), then you don't have any of this extra information, you only have a particular version of the source code. Use the `patch` command to apply a patch.